# How to get the primary keys column of a table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my exercise sheet, my teacher use a python interface with SQLite. But I preferred to work with SQLite on Datagrip.

I'm asked to write a function which take as argument a table and returns the primary key column. I found that writing function in SQLite wasn't possible and that I needed some php interface or whatever.

Anyway as far as it's just training to get some SQL knowledge I tried to write a query for a table which returns a table containing the primary keys of a table.

Using the `PRAGMA table_info (Evenements)` query I get this table :
[image]

So I copied it in a `Test` table and wrote this query which works :

```sql
SELECT name from Test where pk;
```

But I can't replace `Test` by `PRAGMA table_info (Evenements)` or `table_info (Evenements)`.

Do you know if I can directly use the `table_info` result without having to copy it in a new table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you should use is `pragma_table_info()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pragma_table_info('Evenements')
```

You will get info about all the columns of the table `Evenements`.
If you want info only for the primary key add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE pk
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used pk != 0 because `evenements` use a double primary key :
CREATE TABLE Evenements (
    date TEXT,
    motif TEXT,
    lieu TEXT,
    somme float,
    PRIMARY KEY (date,lieu)
); And they are indexed with pk=1 and pk=2

Comment: @Butanium in this case a simple `WHERE pk` will work.